# Passport invalidated during the UK visa application process

Tags: uk-visa, passport

I started the application process for a Global Talent Visa to work in the UK one month ago. Following the prescribed procedure, I used the app to scan my passport and update the data on the application form. Later on, I renewed my passport, and now I am waiting to receive the new document. In the meantime, my old passport (the one that was uploaded on the application form) has been invalidated and its chip is no longer functional, making it an invalid document. I am concerned that if I continue the application with my old, invalidated passport, it will be rejected. Is this the case? Do I have to wait to collect the new document and start the application process again?

Comment: What did UKVI say [when you asked them](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk)?

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will ask them directly!

Comment: When your get their response please [post an answer to your own question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I have had the same issue with Canada -- and yes, I had to wait to collect the new document, and re-submit the application.  Not 100% sure if UK would do different, but this definitely seems like the standard procedure in England-related countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I need to have the passport that I used in my application when starting my job, which must be a valid document. So the correct procedure is to withdraw the previous application and make a new one with the new passport.